# How to determine the current view bounds in split view of Ipad App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have tried following code to determine current view bounds in shouldAutoRotate.. fn

```
UIViewController *temp1 = [appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
float   screenwidth = temp1.view.bounds.size.width;
float   screenheight = temp1.view.bounds.size.height;
```

bt actually when u rotate from one mode to another, it provides the bound values of old one insted the fresh bound values..?
Any one know that how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this in the [`-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:).

`-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` should only be used to determine whether the target orientation is acceptable, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks kenny...
-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method lead me to right answer...

Comment: @Mahesh - If he answered your question, you should mark the little checkbox to the left of this answer in order to accept it.